# Вычитание дат и времени в Js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть такая задача: есть определенная дата, например 25.02.2017 20:32:57 и нужно определить прошло ли 30 минут с того момента как дата была зафиксирована, т.е. если сейчас у нас 21:00 то 30 минут уже прошло, но если меньше, то нужно получить кол-во минут и секунд которые остались до того как 30 минут пройдут.

У меня получилось при помощи библиотеки momentjs получить разницу между текущей датой/временем и той что дана:

```js
var date = moment('2017-02-25T20:32:57.17282');
var timeDiff = moment.utc(moment().diff(date)).format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log(timeDiff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Но теперь я не понимаю как из 30 минут мне вычесть полученное значение и получить строку, которая содержит оставшееся кол-во минут и секунд.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей или просто знает как решить, буду благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагается, что момент времени дан по местному времени.

```
var diff = moment() - moment('2017-02-25T22:32:57.17282');
// Получится, в миллисекундах, сколько прошло времени.

var rest = 30 * 60 * 1000 - diff;
// Это сколько осталось, в миллисекундах, до истечения 30 минут.

var minutes = Math.round(rest / 1000 / 60);
var seconds = Math.round(rest / 1000 - minutes * 60);
// Это сколько осталось, в минутах и секундах, соответственно.
```